# How to center the google map in mobile browser

Tags: javascript, css, google-maps, jquery-mobile

I have been trying really hard to fix the marker of my google map in the center of the screen . But even though I tried all kind of methods its still doesn't appear .

I can only see part of the map at top left corner of the screen in the mobile browser . Please help me out

Here is the JS

```
<script type="text/javascript">          
/*
 * Google Maps documentation: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/basics.html
 * Geolocation documentation: http://dev.w3.org/geo/api/spec-source.html
*/
$( document ).on( "pageinit", "#map-page", function() {
    <?php $coordenadas=explode(',',$fila['Googlemap']);?>

   var defaultLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng('<?php echo $coordenadas[0];?>','<?php echo $coordenadas[1];?>');
    drawMap(defaultLatLng); // Default to Hollywood, CA when no geolocation support
     //var latlng = marker.getPosition();
    function drawMap(latlng) {
        var myOptions = {
            zoom: 10,
            center: latlng,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), myOptions);
        google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');

        // Add an overlay to the map of current lat/lng
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: latlng,
            map: map,
            title: "Greetings!"
        });
        marker.getPosition(latlng) ;
        map.setCenter(latlng);
    }
    $("#map_canvas").width(window.innerWidth).height(window.innerHeight);
}); 
</script>
```

and this is the html

```
<div  data-shadow="false" data-theme="c"  id="map-page"  data-role="page">
<div data-role="header" style="background:#006699 !important;color:#fff;">
<a data-rel="back" href="#pageone"  class="ui-nodisc-icon ui-new-btn" data-icon="location" data-iconpos="notext"  data-corners="true" data-shadow="true" data-iconshadow="true" data-wrapperels="span" data-theme="d" title="Close">Go to Page One</a>
<h1>Header1 </h1>
<a data-rel="back"  href="#pageone"  class="ui-nodisc-icon ui-new-btn" data-icon="delete" data-iconpos="notext"  data-corners="true" data-shadow="true" data-iconshadow="true" data-wrapperels="span" data-theme="d" title="Close">Back</a> 
</div>

    <div role="main" class="ui-content" id="map-canvas">
        <!-- map loads here... -->
    <!---</div> ---->
</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#map-page, #map-canvas { width: 100%; height: 100%; padding: 0; }
```

**Note:** This happens only in mobile browser in desktop it loads fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is page event you are using to trigger map initialization.

**pageinit** is a bad choice because jQuery Mobile is still not fully initialized. **pageshow** is only page event where content height can be calculated correctly, and that heigh is important when google maps v3 api calculates available maps space.

So change this:

```
$( document ).on( "pageinit", "#map-page", function() {
```

to this:

```
$( document ).on( "pageshow", "#map-page", function() {
```

You can find working examples **[here](http://www.gajotres.net/using-google-maps-javascript-api-v3-with-jquery-mobile/)**.

Comment: Okay let me try man I tried removing the pageinit to just $(document).ready(function ) still it doesnot work let me try this one :(

Comment: Don't use $(document).ready(function ) with jQuery Mobile, it is a big NO NO. You should look at a link I provide you in my example. everything you need to know is written there.

Comment: Let me give you few excellent links so you can learn why is important to use page events with jQuery Mobile and when to use each one of them.

Comment: First one will tell you a difference between document ready and pageinit: http://www.gajotres.net/document-onpageinit-vs-document-ready/

Comment: Second one will tell you differences between various page events: http://www.gajotres.net/page-events-order-in-jquery-mobile/

Comment: Thanks man I am really new to this . Very helpful links and the map is showing properly in the center but when I change the orientation it does not center itself

Comment: This is another problem. First you will need to catch resize event. Second thing is, find official google maps v3 api documentation, there's a function used for map refreshing. Use it inside resize event.

Comment: With catching resize event do you mean using this code ??   google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');

Comment: That's the google maps function I was talking about.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52688/discussion-between-vikram-anand-bhushan-and-gajotres)